# Method of Frobenius where the difference between the roots is zero

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this rather mean looking ODE by Method of Frobenius,

$x^2y^{''}+x(1-x)y^{'}-(1-2x)y=0$ about $x_0=0$

For the sake of space and the relevance to my question, I'm not going to summarize the Method of Frobenius and instead assume it is a familiar concept.

The indicial equation to determine the roots will be $r(r-1)+p_0r+q_0$ where,

$p_0=\lim\limits_{x \to 0}[(x)\frac{x(1+x)}{(x^2)}]=1$

$q_0=\lim\limits_{x \to 0}[(x^2)\frac{-(1-2x)}{(x^2)}]=-1$

So the indicial equation is,
$r^2+1=0$ which gives the roots $r=\pm1$

From here, we find the first linearly independent solution by using the typical series substitutions with the larger root $r_1=1$. To find the second solution using the Method of Frobenius, we have three potential solution formats depending upon the difference of the roots. When $r_1-r_2$ is not an integer, when $r_1=r_2$ and when $r_1-r_2$ is a positive integer.

But how do I find the second linearly independent solution when $r_1-r_2=0$? Zero is considered an integer but it doesn't have a positive or negative value.

Comment: One solution is as usual $y_1=(x-x_0)^r\sum a_n(x-x_0)^n$, the other (usually) has a log part: $y_2=y_1\cdot\log(x-x_0)+(x-x_0)^r\sum b_n(x-x_0)^n$